# I want loop to open youtube url on google chrome after every 60 second and refresh it then close

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have tried this code but its not working properly, its open the google chrome one time but not youtube url and after one time open its getting show error anybody could help me make some changes on my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd 
chromedir = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe' 
driver = wd.Chrome(chromedir) 
website = input("http:\youtu.be/RsWCo_xGXxY") driver.open(website) 
def until_func(driver): 
    driver.refresh() 
    orderElem = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=60, poll_frequency=10).until(until_func)
```

Comment: What is the error? Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `chromedriver` path, not `chrome app` path.

Download the [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Also you need to use `driver.get()` not `driver.open()`, and i think is better to use `time.sleep()` instead of `Waits`

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver as wd

# here you need to give path to your `chromedriver` not `chrome` application
chromedriver = 'path/to/your/chromedriver' 
driver = wd.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)
driver.get("http:\youtu.be/RsWCo_xGXxY")

# give in seconds to refresh page
refresh_rate = 60

while True:
    time.sleep(refresh_rate)
    driver.refresh()
```

Comment: Its showing the same error, only open the google chrome not url link only one time

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/Pselenium/newyoutube.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = wd.Chrome(chromedir)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()

Comment: File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0

Comment: import time
from selenium import webdriver as wd

chromedir = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe' 
driver = wd.Chrome(chromedir)
driver.get("http:\\youtu.be/RsWCo_xGXxY")

# give in seconds to refresh page
refresh_rate = 60

while True:
    time.sleep(refresh_rate)
    driver.refresh()

Comment: also you need to download `chromedriver` http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads, you need to give chromedriver path, not path to your chrome app

Comment: Same error received after entering this code : import time
from selenium import webdriver as wd


chromedriver = 'D:\bot\chromedriver_win32.zip/chromedriver.exe' 
driver = wd.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)
driver.get("http:\youtu.be/RsWCo_xGXxY")


refresh_rate = 60

while True:
    time.sleep(refresh_rate)
    driver.refresh()

Comment: extract from zip file `chromedriver.exe` and put in `D:\bot` folder and give this path `D:\\bot\\chromedriver.exe` or `chromedriver = r"D:\bot\chromedriver.exe"`